# google sheets count array elements

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi is there a way to count elements in array like that (im using google sheets)

[image]

I tried googling but didnt find anyone having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

`=counta(split(cellref,","))` will count the number of elements in the array (where cellref is location of your array to be split).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A1; "[^,]"; ))+1
```

[image]

for array:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="";;LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A; "[^,]"; ))+1))
```